# How should I store between 30 and 50 sheets of QuietRock ES?

Tags: drywall, storage, quietrock

I will spare the details of why I am buying this much QuietRock.  For now, let's just assume it makes sense and move on to my question.

As I said, I am buying a large quantity of QuietRock ES to soundproof several rooms and ceilings of my condo (trust me, I found it for a very good price).  I am going to need 30 for my initial job, but will be doing several walls downstairs a few months from now. 
QuietRock ES weighs in at 2.6 lbs per sq ft, so that's a hair over 83 lbs per 4x8 sheet.  This maths out to 2,500 lbs for 30 sheets and 4,160 lbs for 50 sheets.  I need to find a way to store this!

I could use my garage, but drywall needs to be stored flat in a dry place.  I could use my upstairs guest room, but I am questioning the floor's weight capacity.  Assuming I get 50 sheets and use half, that's still 2000+ lbs that I will need to store.  That's a ton of weight.  (See what I did there?)

So what are my options are far as storing this heavy QuietRock?  If I can't, I guess I will just have the dealer ship it to me in smaller quantities as I consume it and just lose out on the bulk rate and pay even more in freight costs =.

Comment: Would renting a storage area be cheaper than freight costs?  You only need a room slightly larger than 4x8.

Comment: I could look into that, but I would need to be certain the storage unit is moisture-free.  I hadn't thought of this option, so thanks for bring it up.

Comment: Typically, North American homes are designed with a nominal load of 40 lbs/sqft.  If you could stack it in two piles, you'd be okay.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the garage if you're worried about the floor's capacity. Place the drywall blocks on the floor first (the truck delivering the drywall usually has a bunch of these to protect the drywall and to make it easier to get the lift under the stack). On top of the blocks, put some plastic if you're worried about moisture in the floor. The drywall goes on top of this, so it's off of the ground. And on top of the drywall, you can put more plastic or tarp if the garage isn't weather proof.

Comment: I agree, the garage  or a storage unit are the only options. Two tons on the second floor would be iffy at best, disastrous at worse. Ambient moisture in an enclosed garage should not be a serious problem if the garage is dry and not stored for a long term, like years.

Comment: I am thinking this is the best option.  I guess I will be parking in the driveway for a few months =\